# Upload Files Security in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1

I'm not good in Laravel 5.1. I need your help guys...

Why does it upload other files that are not on the list in my Requests File?  I want to upload just the **rules** function on my **Request File**.

Here's my **new update** Controller

```
public function store(UploadFiles $filename) {

    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array('filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx');
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        print_r($messages);
    } else {
        $file = $filename->file('filefield');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $entry = new Fileentry();
        $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
        $entry->description = Request::input('description');
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension, File::get($file));
        $entry->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        return redirect('upload');
    }    
}
```

My Requests: **UploadFiles.php**

```
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules() {
    return ['filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx'];
}
```

This is my **index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{route('addentry', [])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
    <input type="file" name="filefield" required>
    <br>

    Description <br>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="textarea" name="description"><br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your rules arr to validator.

Your code should be something like this :

```
$input = Input::all();
$rules = array('filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx');
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    print_r($messages);
} else {
    //your upload code here
}
```

Comment: how should i do that sir?

Comment: try to check if validator fails like above example, then see the result

Comment: I've tried this sir but nothing's happen...it didn't upload anything... T___T

Comment: I already updated my controller above sir...I'm not sure if it is right :)

Comment: you should to change the file name in validator rules to be as your file name: **'filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx',** should be **'filefield' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx',**, where **filefield** is your file name

Comment: You are right. You should make it an answer. It will help others.

Comment: @Gouda Elalfy hello sir i've got the validation but why it didn't upload my files?...i've tried to `dd($file)` and have this result 1UploadedFile {#30 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "error_blog.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -size: 70383
  -error: 0
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your controller, where you're uploading:
Add `use App\Http\Requests\UploadFilesValidationRequest;` and in your controller, implement Dependency Injection, like:

```
public function store(UploadFilesValidationRequest $uploadValidator, UploadFiles $filename){

}
```

**OR**

```
$imageValidator = new UploadFilesValidationRequest;
$imageValidation = Validator::make($fileData,$imageValidator->rules());

if ($imageValidation->fails()){
    dd($imageValidation->messages())
}
```

See, if that works.